# StackOverflow error while using recursive macro in freemarker

Tags: freemarker, ofbiz

I have a requirement to iterate a large number of records using entity list iterator in Freemarker. But, while using a recursive macro, it gives StackOverflow error when it reaches 1000 records only. Below is the code snippet for the same.

```
<#macro recurseTest value>
  ${value.partyId!}
  ${value.firstName!}
  ${value.lastName!}
  <#local tmp = eli.next()!/>
  <#if tmp?has_content>
     <@recurseTest tmp/>
  </#if>
</#macro>
<#assign eli = EntityQuery.use(delegator).from("Person").queryIterator()/>
<br>
<@recurseTest eli.next()!/>
${eli.close()}
```

Comment: Which FreeMarker version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regardless of FreeMarker, it's not a normal practice to process 1000s of elements with recursion (except in some functional languages that have no usual loops construct, but has tail recursion optimizations).  Try to use `#list`. If you can't get a `List` or `Iterator` from that query API (but look into it if you can), as a last resort, you can do this hack (poor man's `do { ... } while (cond)`):

```
<#list 1..100000000 as _>
  ...
  <#if !tmp?has_content><#break></#if>
</#list>
```

(With high enough `incompatible_improvements` FreeMarker configuration setting you  can write `<#list 1.. as _>`, but I don't know what is it set to there. So I have specified some arbitrary high number that would cause timeout or out-of-memory in practice anyway.)